# Linq - customized column

Tags: linq

select ID, 0 as Index from Table;

How do I do this query in linq?

var o = From X in Table Select X.ID, (0 as Index) <- error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var o = from x in Table select new { ID = X.ID, Index = 0 };
```

The `new` keyword here creates a new anonymous type that gets exposed by the query. The first property, `ID`, is populated by the `ID` property from `X`. The second property, `Index`, is given the static value of `0`.